# Watir Webdriver : Can we use watir to test web services with json data format

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am new in testing web services with json data format. I use watir for my automation. So just wanted to know if it can be done with Watir.

I am also looking for other options so all suggestions and links to tutorial are more then welcome.

Comment: Watir can only interact with browsers. If you can access your web service through the browser, it might be possible.

Comment: Hi Justin Ko, Yes i can access my webservice through browser. But how can I filter the response that I am getting. I want to cherry pick the data its sending back.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do it, but it's not the approach I'd take.

I'd look at something like the combination of the Rest-client gem to generate requests and handle the responses, and json-spec to help with validation

'The Cucumber Book' has a chapter on API testing that comes close to this.  They use a slightly different but very similar library (HTTParty), and I don't think they knew about json-spec or they would have used it, but then their validation steps are very rudimentary